# publish to azure doesn't clear previous

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I made a mistake by "publish"ing a different web project to an existing Azure App Service.  So I thought I could *undo* the error by re-publishing the correct web project.  My belief was that a "publish" would erase the previous upload completely in favor of the new upload.  However, this is not the case.  When I try to run after publishing the correct project it fails with a stack trace from the wrong upload.

What is the best way to fix this?  I've spent at least four hours trying different things in the portal as well as researching on the web with no change.  Azure is a great platform but there is so much information and so many tools that I feel overwhelmed.  I would appreciate someone helping me to cut through all this feldercarb to point me in a good direction or two to optimize my efforts.

Cheers!
Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear out additional files during the Publish process.

Try this in Visual Studio.

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click your web project
2. Select "Publish" in the popup menu
3. In the Profile tab, select Azure and log in if you haven't done so already.
4. Go through the tabs (Profile, Connection, Settings)
5. In the Settings tab, expand File Publish Options
6. Check "Remove additional files at destination"

I've included a screenshot below:

[image]

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: You rock!  Thank you very much!  Don't know why that wasn't set before!